# Is `rawToBits` in R system independent?

Tags: r

Is the R base function rawToBits system independent? Will:

```
rawToBits(as.raw(0x01))
```

result in the same order of bits on any system? Or will it depend on the endianness of your operating system? For me, the above statement returns `01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` on a (little endian, tested with `.Platform$endian`) Windows machine.

Comment: From the `?rawToBits` help page: "unpacking is least-significant bit first."

Comment: Oops... I guess this problem is solved and I should read the manual more closely ;).